# Internal error in code generation for pre

Tags: modelica, dymola

I try to avoid the algebraic loop in Modelica by using `pre` operator, but when I use something like `pre(x>0.5)`, there will be an error of `Internal error in code generation for pre`.
And if I use `pre(cond)`, where `cond` is a boolean type variable, there won't be any error.

My question is: Is there some regulation of `pre` operator which requires that I could NOT use expressions within `pre` operator.

Here are the code and screenshot:

```
model WithAlgebraicLoop_Wrong2
  "Demonstration of how to avoid generating algebraic loop,
  but end up with internal error in code generation for pre"
  Real x,y(start=1,fixed=true);
equation 
  when pre(x>0.5) then
    y=1*time;
  end when;
  x=sin(y*10*time);
end WithAlgebraicLoop_Wrong2;
```

[image]

```
model WithAlgebraicLoop_Right "Demonstration of how to avoid generating algebraic loop"
  Real x,y(start=1,fixed=true);
  Boolean cond;
equation 
  cond=x>0.5;
  when pre(cond) then
    y=1*time;
  end when;
  x=sin(y*10*time);
end WithAlgebraicLoop_Right;
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read in the Modelica Language Specification ([section 3.7.3 on event related operators](https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.4/Ch3.html#event-related-operators-with-function-syntax) -> table) that the argument of `pre` needs to be a variable, but not an expression.